# PHP Selecting multiple select options from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, multi-select

I am trying to load a mulitple select from the database to edit.

I am storing the original data in an imploded string (ie "4, 6, 8, 9").

What I want to do is explode that string from the database, then have the values selected when the edit form is loaded.  The values are Float, then 1-52.

Here is the code I have so far, but it does not select the values.

$listing->getWeeksAvail() is just a call that returns the WeeksAvail property in this case "4, 6, 8, 9)

```
<?php
$weeks_available = explode(",", $listing->getWeeksAvail());
if (in_array("Float", $weeks_available)) {
    echo " selected='selected'";
}
?>

>Float</option>
<?php
    for($float=0; $float<=52; $float++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$float\"";
        if (($listing instanceof listing) && $float == $listing->getWeeksAvail()) {
        echo " selected='selected'";
    }
        echo ">$float</option>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your code should be like this:

```
<?php
for ($float=0; $float<=52; $float++) {
    echo "<option value=\"$float\"";
    if (in_array($float, $weeks_available))) {
    echo " selected='selected'";
    }
    echo ">$float</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yea thats working now.  I am having trouble getting the Float value to be selected, but I thought thats how it worked.  I'll keep playing with it. Thanks again

Comment: Use $weeks_available = explode(", ", $listing->getWeeksAvail());

Do you notice the space after the comma? You have used ', ' to implode the values. So, during explode, you need to use the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<?php
$week_available = explode(',', $listing->getWeeksAvail());

foreach ( range(1,42) as $week ) {
   echo "<option value=\"$week\""
        .(in_array($week,$week_available)?"selected=\"selected\"":"")
        .">$week</option>";
}
```